# how to convert column to row in mysql(column having the same value)

Tags: mysql

I have got below format using join query

```
status | vacancy | selected
opening|  10     |   5
closed |  10     |   2
```

but I want to below format, how to get it using 'mysql' query

```
status  |  selected
vacancy |  10
opening |  5
closed  |  2
```

Comment: What are the tables and columns? What is the "join query" you have already used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can select the vacancy and make a union with your other select.

```
select 'vacancy', h.vacancy from hotel h where h.id = 1 
 union all
select status, selected from room where hotel_id = 1
```

Comment: Can you add your select so I can see it?